How to use rclipboard (or another tool to copy from an app) in shinyapps?
I have an app with a "copy to clipboard" button made using writeClipboard function from rclipboard package. I works fine in my computer but when I deploy my app in Shinyapps clicking the button causes the app to reload. I suspect that the problem is that rclipboard is trying to write to the clipboard of the Ubuntu server of Shinyapps instead the clipboard of my computer from the browser, and rclipboard only works in Windows.
Is there a way to have copy paste button working from shiny app running in Shinyapps.io?
